# $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves on Bott$-$Samelson resolutions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $B$ a Borel subgroup. $G/B$ is the corresponding flag variety.

Let $w$ be an element of the Weyl group $W$ with a reduced expression 
$w = s_1 \cdots s_n$. Let $X_w$ be the corresponding Schubert variety in the flag variety, and $BS(s_1,...s_n)$ the corresponding Bott–Samelson resolution.

There is a birational map $$f: BS(s_1,s_2,...,s_n) \rightarrow X_{s_1s_2...s_n} \subset G/B\,.$$.

> What can we say about the (derived) pushforward of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ on $BS(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)$?

Is that the convolution product of some $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves on $X_w \subset G/B$?

Comment: Is the singularity of $X_w$ rational? If it is, then $Rf_*O = O$.

Comment: @Sasha yes, Schubert varieties have rational singularities.

Comment: Are you sure about the equivariance? I would have expected $B$-equivariant objects. The group $G$ acts transitively on the $B$-fixed points of $G/B$, so it does not seem to act on $X_w$. From the question, it seems that you might be interested in looking at the literature on Soergel bimodules.

Comment: Yes, this is only $B$-equivariant, and yes, $Rf_*\mathcal O = \mathcal O$, even when the word is not reduced. One place to read about such things is Brion and Kumar's excellent book (on Frobenius splitting).

Comment: @SeanLawton Maybe it is worth mentioning that some users do not agree to adding MathJax/LaTeX to the titles which are perfectly readable without it. 
See [this discussion on meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/591) or [this message in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29824365#29824365). (As far as I can say, there is no clear consensus about this. But since at the moment you are one of the [most active editors](http://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=editors), I thought that it would be good to make sure you are aware of this.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I do not think the comments thread of a question or answer is the right place to discuss editing practices on MO.  That said, thank you for bringing this to my attention.